# Исключения в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

У меня в `htaccess` такой код

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Нужно сделать так, что бы этот код не работал, если заходишь на сайт через любой поддомен (у меня подключен `wildcard`)

`site.ru` - этот код работает

`poddomen.site.ru` - код не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^poddomen.site.ru$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Только у меня поддомен не определённый, он может быть любым. Нужно исключение сделать для всех поддоменов

Comment: А всё, я понял. Еще раз спасибо)